# Bootstrap navigation collapsing and extra button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, nav

I'm at a loss with my shopping cart. I'd like to see it, even when the navigation is collapsed. I'm using bootstrap for the collapsing

At the moment it looks like this, the shopping cart should be left or right from the collapse button, I don't really care which side.
[image]

How it is (and should be) when the full width is used
[image]

This is my header in html

```
        <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="{{@BASE}}/index">Audio Delight</a></h1>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar"  aria-expanded="true">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <li <check if="{{ @title=='Home' }}">
                            class="active"</check>>
                                <a href="{{@BASE}}/index">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li <check if="{{ @title=='DJ' }}">
                            class="active"</check>>
                                <a href="{{@BASE}}/dj">DJ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li <check if="{{ @title=='Ampli' }}">
                            class="active"</check>>
                                <a href="{{@BASE}}/ampli">Ampli</a>
                            </li>
                            <li <check if="{{ @title=='Light' }}">
                            class="active"</check>>
                                <a href="{{@BASE}}/light">Light</a>
                            </li>
                            <li <check if="{{ @title=='PA' }}">
                            class="active"</check>>
                                <a href="{{@BASE}}/pa">PA</a>
                            </li>
                            <li <check if="{{ @title=='Hardware' }}">
                            class="active"</check>>
                                <a href="{{@BASE}}/hardware">Hardware</a>
                            </li>
                            <li <check if="{{ @title=='AV' }}">
                            class="active"</check>>
                                <a href="{{@BASE}}/av">AV</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="cartNav">
                            <ul id="cart" class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li id="cart" <check if="{{ @title=='Winkelwagen' }}">
                                class="active"</check>>
                                    <a href="{{@BASE}}/shoppingCart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

And my additional css :

```
/*Header*/
div#cartNav {
    float: right;
    width: 56px;
}

ul#cart {
    float: right;
}

li#cart a {
    padding-top: 9px;
}

li#cart {
    display: block;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: you can either use `float` or `position` to manage your cart icon and it needs `CSS` moderation.

Comment: As you can see, I am using float. Otherwise it wouldn't be on the far right.. The problem is that bootstrap maximizes the width of its nav bar.. And there isn't enough room to get the icon next to it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mwatz122/udo21wo9/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
        <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href='#'>Brand</a>

        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href='#'>Shopping Cart</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-left">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href='#'>Home</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-right {
    float: right;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right ul {
    float: right;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
    float: left;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
}
@media all and (max-width:767px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        clear: both;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Comment: Np! I did notice one small bug with the toggle menu in the JSFiddle, so use the edited version if you have any issues with that. (The link has been updated)

Answer (score 0):

Agroup the menu and the shop icon in a div and apply the child float position, like this:

```
<div class="thetwoitems">
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
  <div id="cartNav">
                            <ul id="cart" class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li id="cart" <check if="{{ @title=='Winkelwagen' }}">
                                class="active"</check>>
                                    <a href="{{@BASE}}/shoppingCart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
</div>
```

And apply this to your cart:

```
#cartNav {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Oqmf8Bf.png Doesn't really make it any better :/ Now the menu button drops down too.. Don't really think it's possible tbh. I've been trying all possible permutations for the last 2 hours or so...

Comment: Please, upload a jsfiddle with your problem and i will fix for you.